# Workflow Error | Automatic Activity | Web 8

Tags: web8, workflow

I am implementing translation manger from the automatic activity in the workflow and getting the below error while executing the automatic activity.

State:  Failed
State Message:  Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.WorkflowEngineException: Activity instance '3. Translation' (tcm:X-XXX-XXXXXX) must be in 'Finished' state after script execution by Workflow Agent, but actual state is 'Started'. at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.WorkflowAgentEngine.ProcessActivity(TcmUri activityInstanceId, Boolean isExpirationExecution).

Note - I am using Tridion 2013 SP1 API with web 8 which works with 2013 version. 
Here is my code

```
 var result = ExecuteWorker(new SendTranslationActivityWorker(), CoreServiceClient, ActivityInstance.WorkItems.Select(workItem => workItem.Subject.IdRef).ToList());
            if (result.Success)
            {
                if (result.SuspendActivity)
                {
                    var suspendedActivity = CoreServiceClient.SuspendActivity(ActivityInstance.Id, Definitions.WAIT_FOR_TRANSLATION_REASON, null, Definitions.WAIT_FOR_TRANSLATION_BOOKMARK, NewReadOptions);
                    if (result.Variables != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var variable in result.Variables)
                        {
                            ProcessInstance.Variables.Add(variable.Key, variable.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    CoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(ActivityInstance.Id, GetResumeFinshData(Definitions.NOT_SUSPENDED_MESSAGE), null);
                }
            }
            else {
                CoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(this.ActivityInstance.Id, GetTranslationErrorFinshData(result.Message), null);
            }



private ActivityFinishData GetTranslationErrorFinshData(string message)
        {
            ActivityFinishData finishData = new DecisionActivityFinishData()
            {
                Message = message,
                NextActivity = GetNextActivityByTitle(Utility.GetAppSetting(Definitions.RESUME_TRANSLATION_ERROR_NEXT_ACTIVITY))
            };
            return finishData;
        }
```

Comment: There's a lot of configuration in there.  

Can you confirm that *Utility.GetAppSetting(Definitions.RESUME_TRANSLATION_ERROR_NEXT_ACTIVITY)* returns the correct name for the activity you wish to - and that all *Definitions* are being read with values you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the automatic activity, you don't need to add the NextActivity to the finishData.

If you change your method to:

private ActivityFinishData GetTranslationErrorFinshData(string message)
        {
            ActivityFinishData finishData = new ActivityFinishData()
            {
                Message = message
            };
            return finishData;
        }

Then I'd suggest that the above will work.